# Laravel PubSubHubbub i have subscribed but couldn't receive updates

Tags: laravel-5.1, websub

I am trying to get **real time** feed updates using the **Pubsubhubbup** and **Laravel**, i have created 2 functions one for subscribe and the other one is a callback function.
when the subscribe function called it worked and the callback function receives a confirmation from the hub and respond with the **`hub_challenge`** code, all this works OK but the callback function doesn't receive any feed updates after that although it should receive it from the hub when there are updates but this is not happen !!
can you help to find what is the problem ??
thanks for your time.

the functions

```
public function subscribe(Feed $feed)
{
    $hub_url = "http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com";
    $callback_url = url('feed/getFeedUpdates');

    $subscriber = new Subscriber($hub_url, $callback_url);
    $subscriber->subscribe($feed->feed_url);

    Flash::success('Feed has been saved.');
    return redirect('feed');
}

public function getFeedUpdates(Request $request)
{

    // Subscribe Confirmation
    if ($request->has('hub_mode') && $request->hub_mode == 'subscribe') {

       $response = new Response($request->hub_challenge, 200);
       $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

       return $response;

    } else {    // Receive Updates

        $updates = file_get_contents("php://input");

        // put the updates to the database

    }
}
```

Comment: Having the feed URL would help at least...

Comment: feed URL is :http://feeds.feedburner.com/youm7/UZxT

Comment: i created a basic example with php and it works correctly but in laravel doesn't work i don't know why ??

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Zekry. I am also facing the same problom. Have you find any solution?